# Subjunctive structure with advise

Tags: subjunctives

I know that after subjunctive we should use simple form of the verb, so I was wandering which one of the following sentences is better to use?

(1) Although Morecambe seems to be very attractive, a new travel guide has advised would-be tourists that it **is** a place to avoid.

(2) Although Morecambe seems to be very attractive, a new travel guide has advised would-be tourists that it **be** a place to avoid.

Comment: Sentence (2) seems quite unnatural to me. The subjunctive isn't needed.

Comment: Unless ye be pirates, ye be wanting to avoid option 2.

Comment: Personally, although I find *...that it be **a place to avoid*** completely unacceptable idiomatically, I don't really have a problem with [*...advised that it **be avoided***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22advised+that+it+be+avoided%22) But as @KateBunting says, the subjunctive ***isn't needed*** (so just avoid it! :)

Comment: The second one **could** be adjusted to, “…that it be avoided.” But the first one still sounds more natural. And better yet would be, “…to avoid it.”

Comment: An interesting question.  My first reaction is that of course #2 is completely wrong and unnatural, but when I try to analyze it, I can't explain exactly why, since "I advise that he *leave* the city" sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first rule of the subjunctive is that English doesn't have one ... so don't use it.  (This is a lie but it is close to the truth)

But English used to have a subjunctive and it is still sometimes seen in subordinate clauses.

> I advise he use the indicative

"Use" is in the subjunctive.

But this isn't the situation in your example.  The verb is not in a clause subordinated by the verb "advise" but appears in a content clause. Note the recipient of the advice in the example above is "he", the subject of the subjunctive verb.  In your example the subject of "be" is "it" but the recipient is "would-be tourists".

It is therefore a grammar error to use "be". The verb must be in the indicative form "is".

You may (rarely) see a subjunctive.  You never need to use it, and most native speakers don't use subjective much at all.

> I advise he uses the indicative.